# Repeater not repeating :0) (asp.net)(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, syntax, repeater, sqldatareader

Morning stackoverflow,

I have a repeater, with the following code in my aspx page;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Contactinforepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<h1>Contact Information</h1>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<table width="50%">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><%#Container.DataItem("position")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("surname")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telephone:</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("telephone")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fax:</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("fax")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><%#Container.DataItem("email")%></td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>

<SeparatorTemplate>
<br /><hr /><br />
</SeparatorTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Then I have this code in my aspx.vb to get the data;

```
If did = 0 Then
            s = "sql works on db server"
            x = New SqlCommand(s, c)
            x.Parameters.Add("@contentid", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            x.Parameters("@contentid").Value = contentid
            c.Open()
            r = x.ExecuteReader
            r.Read()
            Contactinforepeater.DataSource = r
            Contactinforepeater.DataBind()
        End If
        c.Close()
        r.Close()

        If Not did = 0 Then
            s = "sql works on db server"
            x = New SqlCommand(s, c)
            x.Parameters.Add("@contentid", SqlDbType.Int)
            x.Parameters("@contentid").Value = contentid
            x.Parameters.Add("@did", SqlDbType.Int)
            x.Parameters("@did").Value = did
            c.Open()
            r = x.ExecuteReader
            r.Read()
            Contactinforepeater.DataSource = r
            Contactinforepeater.DataBind()
        End If
        r.Close()
        c.Close()
```

If 'did' is or is not '0' I still get no data outputted to the page. I just get the 'contact information' h1 header from the header template.

I've tested the value of s in sqlsms and it works fine. Position, surname, telephone, fax, email all exist in the db. The particular page I am checking exists and has 1 set of contact information attached.

Where am I going wrong?

#### Thanks!

ps. Does my syntax *appear* correct?

pps. I am also open to different ways of achieving the same result. I tried via an sqldatasource but ran into problems when using variables as params (there is no option to select them, only controls, querystring etc)

Comment: have you checked within your if statements to ensure they are executing, perhaps with a Response.Writeline ?

Comment: Yes after the contactinforepeater.databind() in both blocks I have added a response.write(did) and both are showing the correct values.. first one = 0, second one = 984

Comment: have you checked with the debugger, if the right if-statements execute and whether the DataSource contains > 0 rows?

Comment: im checking against a db record that definately has rows and outputs 1 complete set of contact information with no nulls present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the codebehind blocks to;

```
 If r.HasRows Then
                Contactinforepeater.DataSource = r
                Contactinforepeater.DataBind()
            End If
```

Cheers